# Import / Dependency Cannot be Resolved in Maven

Tags: java, maven, import, pom.xml

I'm using a program that relies on the following two imports:

```
import org.lwjgl.opencl.CLDevice;
import org.lwjgl.opencl.CLPlatform;
```

Eclipse is reporting that the "import cannot be resolved" even though I've added LWJGL OpenCL as a dependency to my project.

Here's a snapshot of my POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl-opencl</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I've read somewhere that these classes only exist in an earlier version so I tried changing the version to all of the versions found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lwjgl/lwjgl-opencl) ( from 3.1.0 to 3.1.6) but none of them resolved the issue.

Is there an earlier/different version that is not on the Maven repository page? If not where could I find the said class?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to build on command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are using the abandoned [lwjgl v2](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl) library. It can be found in another Maven repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Nice find! Works perfectly now. Thanks